# Find a list of directories on server side virtual directory and print out the list using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new at this web stuff so please bear with me. I'm attempting to read a list of directories from the server and print them out on the web page. I am using Tomcat and have directory listings enabled for a virtual directory located at localhost/files. I want to parse that directory listing and get the name of all the folders and print it on my main page at localhost (index.html) (I'm going to eventually make a loop to create links for items within them from this). Any idea how to do this with Javascript or something that does not need a new language/framework installed on the server?

So far I have the following which allows me to print all the contents from the directory listing on the main page:

```
<script>
var directory = "/files";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', directory, false); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
var ret = xmlHttp.responseText;
var fileList = ret.split('\n');
for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
   
}
```

Contents of the directory listing:

```
<!doctype html><html>
<head>
<title>Directory Listing For [/]</title>
<style>body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style> </head>
<body><h1>Directory Listing For [/]</h1><hr class="line"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><font size="+1"><strong>Filename</strong></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="+1"><strong>Size</strong></font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="+1"><strong>Last Modified</strong></font></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/files/DataRetrieval.config.xml"><tt>DataRetrieval.config.xml</tt></a></td>
<td align="right"><tt>0.6 kb</tt></td>
<td align="right"><tt>Mon, 09 Mar 2020 04:47:57 GMT</tt></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/files/DataRetrievalTask.exe"><tt>DataRetrievalTask.exe</tt></a></td>
<td align="right"><tt>21.4 kb</tt></td>
<td align="right"><tt>Mon, 09 Mar 2020 04:52:27 GMT</tt></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/files/DataRetrievalTask.pdb"><tt>DataRetrievalTask.pdb</tt></a></td>
<td align="right"><tt>25.4 kb</tt></td>
<td align="right"><tt>Mon, 09 Mar 2020 04:52:27 GMT</tt></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/files/HMI/"><tt>HMI/</tt></a></td>
<td align="right"><tt>&nbsp;</tt></td>
<td align="right"><tt>Wed, 10 Mar 2021 13:10:49 GMT</tt></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">
<td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="/files/HMIApplication/"><tt>HMIApplication/</tt></a></td>
<td align="right"><tt>&nbsp;</tt></td>
<td align="right"><tt>Thu, 04 Feb 2021 14:25:11 GMT</tt></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/10.0.2</h3></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, on the directory list, Tomcat includes a slash after all folder names, but not file names. You should be able to check for that in your javascript to detect which one is a folder.

```
for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    let file = fileList[i];
    if (file.endsWith("/")) {
       // Should be a directory
    }
}
```

Edited answer to work with html included:

```
fetch(YOUR_URL).then(resp=>resp.text()).then(html=> {
    // Use an iframe to allow for parsing of HTML easily
    let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    // Must add iframe to body for it to be able to work
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.append(iframe);

    // Set the content of the iframe
    let idoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    idoc.write(html);

    // Take the links inside the first table because there's probably other links on the page
    let links = idoc.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].getAttribute("href").endsWith('/')) {
            console.log(links[i].getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
    document.body.remove(iframe);
});
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to match "/". But you are correct in that each folder name does indeed end with that. I guess this brings up another question: "When parsing, am I parsing the raw html or am I parsing the text I see on the screen?" - I'm guessing the html, because I am able to match each file & folder name by using file.includes("href");, but it seems endsWith doesn't seem to work. Basically it doesn't seem to match anything via endsWith no matter what I put in there.

Comment: Can you post the html of the directory list page for me? Right click the page and press "View page source" near the bottom and update your answer please.

Comment: I added a portion of it since it's so large. It includes some files and some folders.

Comment: Okay I tried to copy and pasting this into my HTML code (inside script tags) and it doesn't seem to work. I put in /files for the URL (because it's localhost/files) and tried several permutations including localhost/files. I don't have an ide for javascript or anything and not sure how to see if there is error output (just haven't gotten that far yet and coming from Java/C development). Also what is with the big depature of methods? Not sure what an iframe is and why you would use this versus the simple parsing, can you elaborate more? Thanks.