# Javascript String replace not working while using iframe

Tags: javascript

I've seen quite a few issues about this on the site, but all of them seem to be related to Strings' immutability. I don't think that is my issue here, and for some reason, this string replace doesn't seem to work. The web page's content is the full path (basically the XML interpretation of) /files/somefolder/ and I'm trying to get the folder name. I currently get "/files/somefolder/" printed out on the screen. I would expect this to output 'somefolder'. Any idea why it's not? (also, I'm new to Javascript, coming from a Java/C perspective, so please include an explanation as to why it's happening in any answer so I can learn):

My javascript is called filescanner.js:

```
var directory = "/files";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', directory, false); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
var ret = xmlHttp.responseText;

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(ret, 'text/html');

let links = doc.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].getAttribute("href").endsWith('/')) {
            document.write(links[i].getAttribute("href").replace("/\/files\//g","").replace("/\//g",""));
            document.write("<br />");
        }
}
```

My main site is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css" media="screen"/>
<title>
Remote Client
</title>
<body>

<center>Ensure that Java Runtime Environment is installed on your machine before starting </center>
<br>
<center><a href="Installers/jre-8u91-windows-i586.exe" class="button">Install Java</a></center>
<br>
<h2>Launch HMI Remote Client</h2>

<script src="filescanner.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the iframe url on the same domain as the page running the code?

Comment: Yes, it's localhost for the main page (outputting text and where i have the i frame) and it's parsing a page localhost/files

Comment: @evolutionxbox They're created an `iframe` with no `src` and using `document.write` on it. I'd expect that it's `about:blank`.

Comment: Why use an iframe to write links/html? FYI synchronous requests are typically a bad idea.

Comment: @Tacitus86 If you wanted to show `/files`, just set the `src` of the `iframe` to that URL. Don't bother with the `document.write`.

Comment: Note that using synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` is a terrible practice and has been deprecated by browser vendors. You should be seeing a warning in dev tools console regarding the deprecation

Comment: TBH I'm new and this was suggested in another question. I just don't know any alternative. This applies to the synchronous request and iframe comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66764400/find-a-list-of-directories-on-server-side-virtual-directory-and-print-out-the-li/66764809?noredirect=1#comment118022082_66764809

Comment: I would isolate the string replacement, to the console for example, and see if it does what expect. If it does, you know the problem is not the string replacement. If it does not, you can ask a more targeted question.

Comment: @Erik console.log writes the same as the document.write

Comment: `let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');` or `parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");` <-- no reason to use iframe.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you. I wasn't sure the purpose as to why the responder suggested iframe in my original question. I was trying to learn about it to figure out why but couldn't see a reason even after that. I edited my question to include the new code.

Comment: @charlietfl can you suggest how to do it with an ansync request?

Comment: @Tacitus86 I mean make a few test cases and check if they end up what you expect after the string replacement. Also it seems like you want to use a regexp but you actually use a string. `s.replace(/\/files\//g, '')` is the right syntax.

Comment: @Erik that is the solution to the question. I changed that and it worked. Feel free to post as the answer.